# Fortran IF statement without logical expression

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran77

I am converting an old code in Fortran which I think is a 77. there a couple of usage of IF in the following way that I can't realize what it does:

```
    IF(x1-x2) 12, 13, 14

12  WRITE(*,*) x1
    .
    .
    .
13  y=...
    .
    .
14  DO x=x1,x2
    IF(x-x2) 33, 34, 40
    .
    .
    .
```

The code complies and runs fine and it produces the results. Has anyone encountered such a usage of IF?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6789946/3157076.

Comment: Been here several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [arithmetic `IF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_IF).  It branches to the first, second, or third label depending on whether the expression is negative, zero, or positive.

In very old versions of Fortran (or FORTRAN), it was the only form of `IF` statement that was available.

It's probably a little odd to see it used in a version as recent as Fortran 77, which had a more modern logical `IF`. The feature was declared obsolescent in Fortran 90, but I wouldn't be surprised if more modern Fortran compilers still support it.

Comment: Oh ok,so the order is 1st,2nd,3rd for negative,zero,positive. thanks

Comment: gfortran still support it, yes. I'm using it with some legacy code in Fortran 77.

Comment: In 1984 u was telling my students using it was bad practice and it is probably going to become obsolete soon. Welcome to to the world of real computing.

Comment: ah yes i remember it well from my first program in 73